# Renaming columns from a df in batch

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with GDP data. The first few columns contain important data about the countries (which I have renamed it the way I wanted it) but it then goes into a long list of columns displaying a column per year from 1960 to 2015 with each year's GDP. In addition, the columns' names have got messed up and they are named sequentially with the word 'Unnamed' i.e 'Unnamed: 4', 'Unnamed: 5', etc.

My idea was to rename all the 'Unnamed' columns to each of the years (from 1960 to 2015). For example *{'Unnamed 4': 1960, 'Unnamed 5': 1961, etc}*. So I tried to write the code below:

```
GDP = pd.read_csv('world_bank.csv')
GDP = GDP.rename(columns={"Data Source": "Country", "World Development Indicators": "Country Code", "Unnamed: 2": "Indicator name", "Unnamed: 3": "Indicator Code"})   
GDP = GDP.replace({'Data Source': {'Korea, Rep.': 'South Korea', 'Iran, Islamic Rep.': 'Iran', 'Hong Kong SAR, China': 'Hong Kong'}})

#Below is what I wrote to try to iterate through
GDP = GDP.rename(columns={["Unnamed: "+str(i)+": "+str(j) for i in range(4, 60) for j in range(1960, 2016)]})
```

But when I use that code it give this error:

> **TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'**

Any thoughts how to do this?

Comment: you don't need the lists just use a dict comp `{"Unnamed: "+str(i)+": "+str(j) for i in range(4, 60) for j in range(1960, 2016)}`

Answer (score 1):

You can directly use `dict comprehension` in python like:

```
GDP.rename(columns = {"Unnamed: "+str(i): str(1956+i) for i in range(4, 60)})
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass a dictionary to the `rename` function containing existing column names as keys and the replacing ones as values. You can see an example in the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html).